# checking and setting variable, efficiently

Tags: java, c, vba

I am new to programming and have a simple question: is there a "better" or more efficient way of doing this...

```
if (x != 0) {
  y = x;
}
```

or

```
if (getMethod() != null) {
  value = getMethod();
}
```

I'm new to programming and above code (esp the 2nd one) seems inefficient.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You second example can suffer from a "Time of check, to time of use" weakness.  If the first invocation of getMethod() returns non-null, it is possible that your second invocation will return null.  A better way to do it would be:

```
   value = getMethod();
   if(NULL != value)
   {
       /* use value as planned */
   }
   else
   {
       /* handle a null value, probably an error */
   }
```

if interested, you can read more about TOCTTOU weaknesses [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

For your first example, I don't really see a better way of doing this.

N.B. This answer is from the perspective of a C programmer (seeing as how C was one of your tags).

Hope this helps
- T.

Comment: `value = getMethod();` at the beginning of your example is wrong. The OP wants to update `value` only if `getMethod();` returns anything but `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it shorter

```
  if ( x )  y = x;
```

is the same as

```
 if (x != 0) {
  y = x;
 }
```

And

```
 if ( getMethod() ) value = getMethod();
```

is the same as

```
 if (getMethod() != null) {
   value = getMethod();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First code snippet:**
In C any non-zero value is treated as `true` and `0` treated as `false`. So, for the first example, you can rewrite it as:

```
if (x) {
  y = x; // this line will be executed if x not equal to zero
}
```

**Second code snippet:**
You called `getMethod()` twice which is not efficient. As per your code, you are assigning the return value of `getMethod()` into `value` if `getMethod()` returns anything but `NULL`. So you can use a *temporary* variable to check the return value of `getMethod()`, like following:

```
temp = getMethod(); 
if (temp != null) {
  value = temp;
}
```

That will reduce calling same method twice.